# Jssor Fullscreen Width (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slideshow, fullscreen, jssor

I just installed the Jssor Slider Plugin on my Wordpress site. Is there a possiblity, as shown in the demo, to create a (responsive) fullscreen width slider? I couldn't find that option.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example, hope it help.

http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider-new-api.source.html

Comment: How do I implement the above in wordpress?? I have no problem doing it on a static html page but I just can't seem to figure out how to make the slider full-width in WordPress :(

Comment: Here is a link to the demo page I'm implementing this on: http://demo.shillongtitude.com/scroll-site/

Comment: Please check out a third party jssor slider wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/jssor-slider

Comment: I did :( That is the plugin I used for my site but I can't find a full-width option in the plugin. There are only specific pixel widths that can be specified :(

Comment: Please ask the developer then.

Comment: why jssor plugin is not available in wordpress https://wordpress.org/plugins/jssor-slider/ @jssor

Comment: For now, it's available to download here `http://www.jssor.com/wordpress/version/package*`

Comment: jssor slider wordpress plugin is now available at wordpress.org/plugins/jssor-slider